# geopandas .explore - How to set colormap opacity?

Tags: python, colors, polygon, geopandas, folium

I am plotting **polygon map** of a city district and set colormap base on **area**, I would like to set background tile as **OpenStreetMap**. but the result is that, with many details and colors of the OpenStreetMap, I feel quite fussy about how it looks.

```
import geopandas as gpd
df_polygon = gpd.read_file(path)

import folium
m=df_polygon.explore(column='AREA_BMA'
                    ,tooltip={"SUBDISTR_1"}
                    ,popup=True
                    ,cmap='Greens'
                    ,legend=False
                    ,style_kwds=dict(color="black",weight=1, opacity=0.4)
                    ,name="Polygon")

folium.LayerControl().add_to(m)

m
```

[image]

---

I have tried using ...

```
opacity=0.7
min_opacity=0.7
fillOpacity=0.7
alpha=0.7
```

but got Error: unexpected keyword argument.

and also tried to set opacity of openstreetmap, but this is not what I wanted.

```
folium.TileLayer('openstreetmap', control=True, opacity=0.3,name="openstreetmap opacity 0.3").add_to(m)
folium.LayerControl().add_to(m)
```

[image]

Would anybody know a way to set the opacity of colormap?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to pass `fillOpacity` within `style_kwds`.

```py
m=df_polygon.explore(column='AREA_BMA',
                    tooltip={"SUBDISTR_1"},
                    popup=True,
                    cmap='Greens',
                    legend=False,
                    style_kwds=dict(color="black",weight=1, opacity=0.4, fillOpacity=.7),
                    name="Polygon"),
```